# Black tiff output Windows XP but works in Windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-xp, magicknet

On start I emphasize that I searched on the internet, do my own tests and failed -> that's why I'm asking You guys.

I've got this problem that on SOME (not every) environments that are based on Windows XP my program doesn't work entirely correct. Unfortunetely I can't determine what are the differences between one and another machine that use Windows XP. I've tried update'ing Windows, install WIC etc. -> doesn't make any difference.

I'm displaying tiff on about 3/4 size of screen and everything is great except situation when it is fit to width. I can zoom in or zoom out and then it works.

Of course i can hard code logic like

`if (environment == windowsXP) then display on 75% screen size`

but I and my Boss don't find it professional.

I'm trying to change input tiff by Magick.NET using this code

```
using (var list = new MagickImageCollection())
        {
            list.Read(file);
            for (int id = 0; id < list.Count; id++)
            {
                using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage())
                {
                    image.Density = new MagickGeometry(300, 300);
                    image.Depth = 8;
                    image.Strip();
                    image.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.LZW;
                    image.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.GRAY;
                    image.Write(destFolder);
                }
            }
        }
```

but it doesn't work (conversion works, but it is still black in my program).

Greetings.

Comment: Could it be a graphics card driver issue?

Comment: Probably not because in my case there are two separate companies that had this problem and the hardware is completely different. Of course I will check that posibility.

Comment: You might want to check the whether the initial DPI of the image is correctly interpreted/decoded under the buggy environment.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean?